# Get proportions of letters compared to length of a string

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def letter_proportion(seq):
    pro_dict = {}
    char_count = {}
    for character in seq:
        if character in char_count:
            char_count[character] += 1
        else:
            char_count[character] = 1
    print(char_count)
    for character, value in pro_dict.items():
        pro_dict[character] = character/len(seq)
    return pro_dict
```

I am trying to get the proportion saved into a string, but not able to. And my `pro_dict` returns `{}`. How would I output proportions for `pro_dict`?

I am expecting something like {A:.333, C: .444}

Comment: Please take a look at [*How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: What is `Write her` supposed to do?

Comment: How could `pro_dict` ever be anything but empty?  It's initialized to `{}`, then there's a loop that's meant to set elements in it, but it's iterating over `pro_dict` itself, which you know is empty.  So of course it stays empty.

Comment: You are looping over the contents of `pro_dict`, before it *has* any contents - that second loop is going to execute zero times.  I assume that you want to iterate over `char_count`, instead.

Answer (score 1):

## You iterate over wrong dict

In your code, you iterated over `pro_dict` who is empty. You need to iterate over `char_count` to get all letters and corresponding count.

If you want a string, just cast the returned value in a string.
You can do that inside the function or outside. Example: `return str(pro_dict)`

## Simplify with collections.defaultdict

[Python docs: collections.defaultdict(default_factory=None, /[, ...])](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```py
import collections


def letter_proportion(seq):
    pro_dict = {}
    char_count = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for character in seq:
        # default dict call int if the character is not in the dict
        char_count[character] += 1
    # char_count=defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'A': 5, 'T': 4, 'G': 6, 'C': 5})

    for character, value in char_count.items():
        pro_dict[character] = value/len(seq)
    return pro_dict


print(letter_proportion('GAATTTCCCC'))  # 10 length long
# {'G': 0.1, 'A': 0.2, 'T': 0.3, 'C': 0.4}
```

## Simplify with collections.Counter

[Python docs: collections.Counter([iterable-or-mapping])](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```py
import collections


def letter_proportion(seq):
    pro_dict = {}
    char_count = collections.Counter(seq)
    # char_count=Counter({'G': 6, 'A': 5, 'C': 5, 'T': 4})

    for character, value in char_count.items():
        pro_dict[character] = value/len(seq)
    return pro_dict


print(letter_proportion('GAATTTCCCC'))  # 10 length long
# {'G': 0.1, 'A': 0.2, 'T': 0.3, 'C': 0.4}
```

## collections.Counter + Dict comprehension

[Python docs: dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-dictionary-comprehension)

```py
import collections


def dna_prob1(seq):
    char_count = collections.Counter(seq)
    return {character: count/len(seq) for character, count in char_count.items()}

print(letter_proportion('GAATTTCCCC'))  # 10 length long
# {'G': 0.1, 'A': 0.2, 'T': 0.3, 'C': 0.4}
```

Comment: So I would return pro-dict to get the value I want.